# sqlite3 db is locked

Tags: ruby, sqlite, ubuntu, samba

I am on Ubuntu10. 
Create new db file with

```
touch development.db
```

Want my migrations

```
rake db:migrate
```

but get locked error

```
SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked
```

How it can be locked?!

---

**update** it can be locked by samba. it's shared folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have run into this problem myself. I have found that the only way to avoid the lock being placed on a file like this is to add the `nobrl` option to your mount. The entry in your `/etc/fstab` might look something like this:

```
//<SERVERNAME>/<REMOTEPATH> /<LOCALMOUNTPOINT>/<LOCALPATH> cifs credentials=/home/<LOCALUSERNAME>/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775,nobrl 0 0
```

This is loosely following the ubuntu wiki page found at: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Answer (score 1):

You should try `rake db:create` instead of `touch`. This always works for me. Maybe there's a problem with the migrations itself?

Comment: migrations are ok.. i've tried them on win7. everything was normal

Answer (score 1):

i think it was locked by **samba**.

i put development.db in other non-shared folder and everything works as expected